# How to get the runtime of an R script?

Tags: r, runtime

I am running a single script in R using **source('scriptname.R')**.

I would like to get the running time of this script.

Can someone advise me on how I can do this?

Comment: take a look at `?system.time`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*tl;dr*: Wrap `system.time(source("scriptname.R"))` around it.

Longer answer: Read the "Writing R Extensions" manual about profiling your code, and look at a few of the profiling packages which help aggregate the raw profiling data.  The newest, and possibly nicest is Hadley's [lineprof package on github](https://github.com/hadley/lineprof).

Answer (score 4):

[`system.time`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.time.html) should do:

```
system.time(source('scriptname.R'))
```